# how can I change plugin_dir_url to another folder?

Tags: wordpress

I have this wordpress plugin for shorcodes. I´m trying to implement this in my theme without the need of installing it.

How can I change this 2 lines of code where it says "plugin_dir_url", so it grabs the files from my template folder?

```
class SYMPLE_TinyMCE_Buttons {
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array(&$this,'init') );
}
function init() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;     
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {  
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array(&$this, 'add_plugin') );  
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array(&$this,'register_button') ); 
        **wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'sympleShortcodesVars', array('template_url' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) );**
    }  
}  
function add_plugin($plugin_array) {  
   **$plugin_array['symple_shortcodes'] = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'js/symple_shortcodes_tinymce.js';**
   return $plugin_array; 
}
function register_button($buttons) {  
   array_push($buttons, "symple_shortcodes_button");
   return $buttons; 
}
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_bloginfo("template_directory")` should do it.

Codex: [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

Comment: can you please write it as an example? should I remove (__FILE__)?? thanks